# Translating attribute on different store views

Tags: attributes, store-view

In the backend I have given my attribute label different names, but on the frontend both store views use the admin label. 
The code that gets the label;

```
echo $_attribute->getLabel()
```

How do I make this store view specific?

Answer (score 6):

Go to

app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml

find

```
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
```

replace with

```
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel() ?></label></dt>
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: login in your magento backend.

Step 2: Catalog >> Attributes >> manage Attributes.

Step 3: Open your Attribute.

Step 4: Got to Tab `Manage Label / Options`.

Step 5: You can hear Specify Store vise Label. Magento Will call automatic when that store will load.

This is simple way to show the attribute Label.

you can use below code.

```
  <?php
  $productAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attr);
  $_label = $productAttribute->getStoreLabel(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName());
  echo $_label;
  ?>
```

The above code will give the attribute label as per store wise.

Let me know if any comments.

Comment: Hi Keyul. Like I wrote in the question, the problem is that I've already done this but sadly it doesn't show on the frontend.

Comment: Update your cache

Comment: All caching is disabled.

Comment: then check have you install any custom module that will affect